# In Visual Studio 2012 or any free tool how can I find all the methods in my solution that reference a particular assembly?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, find-all-references

I'd like to find out all the places in my solution where we call various libraries for documentation.

The way I'm currently doing this is by looking at the assembly in the object browser to find its namespaces, then searching the entire solution for "using *thatNamespace*", commenting those using statements out, and looking at the resulting build errors.

I have a feeling there is a better way though.  Isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how helpful this will be, but if you right click the references directory in your solution explorer, you can click 'optimize references', from there you can see what is used and what isn't used.

It also has a tree structure where you can dig into where it was used, but it doesn't actually tell you in the pop-up tool so you have to open each file. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot perhaps?  Maybe I should have been more specific but I don't see it in VS 2012 Professional

Comment: I apologize, I glossed over that in the title, I tried this in 2013 and don't currently have access to 2012 on this computer.